# How to make a Carousel with more than 3 images in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm trying to add more images to my Carousel in Bootstrap. I initially just added this (below) to the ordered list that is class="carousel-indicators"

```
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="3"></li>
```

And the new slide (below) inside the div class="carousel-inner" tag along with the other three initial slides.

```
     <div class="carousel-inner mx-auto">
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="pic.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="pic">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

and when I run the website, scroll through the carousel, and get to the last picture it breaks and I can't go back to any previous pictures or go forward anymore.

I tried the code that was listed in another question titled "Bootstrap 4 Multi Carousel show 4 images instead of 3" and that just broke the carousel completely. Three of the four images appear at once on the screen in a column, one containing the carousel controls. When you press any of the controls the carousel disappears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a *Slider with 5 images*, I hope useful for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Make the image fully responsive */
    
    .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                  <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="4"></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580238047299-558e582427bf?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=420&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=680" alt="slide one" width="1100" height="500">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide One</h3>
          <p>Description slide one</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572130456602-fed3019a174e?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=420&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=680" alt="slide two" width="1100" height="500">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide Two</h3>
          <p>Description slide two</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550828553-bb30dc55dc25?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=420&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=680" alt="slide three" width="1100" height="500">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide Three</h3>
          <p>Description slide three</p>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504406438164-c0e042535100?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=420&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=680" alt="slide four" width="1100" height="500">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide Four</h3>
          <p>Description slide Four</p>
        </div>
      </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571407509209-73d3e4a45892?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=420&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=680" alt="slide five" width="1100" height="500">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide Five</h3>
          <p>Description slide Five</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here a example. The class it's from Bootstrap.

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you mentioned does not relate to the question. Yes, it is about Carousel but the question was about adding more than 3 images, while your code only adds 3 images.

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows a carousel with 5 images.

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>...</h5>
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>...</h5>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>...</h5>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="4.jpg" alt="Fourth slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>...</h5>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="5.jpg" alt="Fifth slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>...</h5>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: This example is great, but it would be even more helpful if you included what version of bootstrap you are linking. And what script you are also linking too.